# Reversed Multiple Pair

Tags: code-golf, math, number, decision-problem

## Intro

Two numbers are a *reversed multiple pair* if they satisfy the following property:

$$
a\cdot b = \operatorname{reversed}( (a-1)\cdot b )
$$

Here, \$\operatorname{reversed}()\$ means to reverse the digits of a number (e. g `123` becomes `321`.)

## Example

$$
a=6,\quad b=9,\quad
6\cdot 9=54,\quad 
5\cdot 9=45
$$

As you can see, \$45\$ is the reversed version of \$54\$.

## Task

Given two integers, \$a\$ and \$b\$, output if these two numbers is a reversed multiple pair.

## Test Cases

```
6 9 => True
4 5 => False
3 2178 => True
34 2079 => True
7 8 => False
600 100 => False
46 1089 => True
817 503 => False
6 9009 => True
321 81 => False
10 1089 => False
```

Shortest code wins!

Comment: Suggest test case: `321 81 => False`. An answer checking `b` for divisibility with 9 will pass all existing test cases but not this one.

Comment: @chunes implemented

Comment: Is `10 1089` truthy or falsy? Currently, different answers don't agree on this testcase.

Comment: May I assume inputs are positive? Or what is expected output for `-5 9`?

Comment: @tsh Inputs will always be positive.

Comment: Shouldn’t 10 1089 be false?

Comment: @tsh why should it be false?

Comment: reverse(9*1089)=reverse(9801)=1089≠10890=10*1089

Answer (score 9):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 76 bytes

```
(load library
(d f(q((a b)(e(to-base 10(*(- a 1)b))(reverse(to-base 10(* a b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtBCoMwFET3nmKWPwXhx2iix0kwQiDUNkrB06fB301X85g3c6bnldPxqpXy7lfkFIovV0crNnoTeQRFkc69D/6I0EwP6uGhVVCKSvzEcvzrJkOlDRaL6lqOmO40GLSbBUcM7EQ7SGeZ253lYhvO4mftMLGRDRZmqc2gm7pR829dvw)

Answer (score 8):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
-₁ʰ×↔~×?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X/dRU@OpDYenP2qbUnd4uv3//9EmZjqGBhaWsf8B)

#### Explanation

```
           Input = [A, B]
-₁ʰ        Compute [A-1, B]
   ×       Compute (A-1) × B
    ↔      Reverse digits
     ~×?   It can be unmultiplied into [A,B]
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:str(a*b)==str(~-a*b)[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzNCsIwEITveYrFUyKxpP@1kB59Am/qIaUtBtImJFHoxVevDUjrYZeZnW/WzP6pp3QZ@H1RYmw7AYK2tfMWi2NLOA/qcwr6Vten@LHI0Wjrwc0ODdqCAjkFEznfyalGIKnmKnJGSY8PvDkQFD7y4ygM7t9CUfkLCaEIjJWTxytAh7AJDQjWhCwFnIE3cLWvHmWQB30RyvUohSQuqy1LM0hYubMlVDtbMAbxOtshK1Zf7XQVl5Cz9K8BZ8a2/As)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
’×ṚḌ⁼×
```

A dyadic Link accepting \$a\$ and \$b\$ that yields `1` if \$a\times b = \text{reversed}( (a - 1)\times b )\$, `0` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//4oCZw5fhuZrhuIzigbzDl////zb/OTAwOQ)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8zD0x/unPVwR8@jxj2Hp/8/vFz/UdOa//@jo810FCxjdRSiTXQUTEG0sY6CkaG5BZgJFDMyMAdLm@sogMXMDAx0FAwNDMBazEBMC7C8hSFQhamBMVgN0EgDA7CwsZEhUKNhbCwA).

#### How?

```
’×ṚḌ⁼× - Link: a, b
’      - a-1
 ×     - (a-1) times b
  Ṛ    - reverse the digits of (a-1)×b
   Ḍ   - convert back to an integer
     × - a×b
    ⁼  - equal?
```

Comment: how do you code in jelly?

Comment: @DialFrost the same way you code in other languages:P

Comment: @DialFrost see the [tutorial](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Tutorial) to get started.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 9 bytes

Anonymous tacit infix function, taking \$a\$ as left argument and \$b\$ as right argument.

```apl
×≡∘⌽⍥⍕×-⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn///D0R50LH3XMeNSz91Hv0ke9Uw9P133Uteh/2qO2CY96@x51NT/qXfOod8uh9caP2iY@6psaHOQMJEM8PIP/mymkKVgqPOqdqxBSVJrKZQLkmoK5bok5xalcxkC@kaG5BUKFMUiJkYE5kiZzoIgFkiYzAwOgiCGQRIiZmIGFLJC0WRiCNJoaGCNrBTnHwABJlbGRIch4Q4QiAA) (Uses Extended because TIO hasn't updated to 18.0)

`×` [Does] the product

`≡∘` match the…

`⌽⍥` reversed, when both are…

`⍕` stringified

`×` product

`-` minus

`⊢` the right argument[?]

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 9 bytes

```
,’$×DU⁼¥/
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCIs4oCZJMOXRFXigbzCpS8iLCIiLCIiLFsiMzQiLCIyMDc5Il1d)

```
,’$×DU⁼¥/    Main Link; dyad accepting a, b
,’$          pair: [a, a - 1]
   ×         multiply: [ab, (a - 1)b]
    D        to digit list
        /    reduce between the two:
     U       is the reverse of the former
      ⁼      equal to the latter?
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <sup><s>47</s></sup> 39 bytes

```
[ over * dup present reverse dec> - = ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9NC4JAEL3vr3jnIFk/0rXIa3TpEp2iw6ITRanb7hqE@Ntt@0AdGHgfw8y8s8xtrfvDfrvbLCGNqXODG@mK7iilvUBpMlRZGHo0VOVkvrKnpDakP661L6WvbmLFWMvgqkWKGN0fLxANOPATgXCkPEkRjrZAMmCfc8SuRy5SRJO1PITwx/mU8@nVMPCd7WjH@iPqp/t1hqJRQx5NTjOEgvIMc6xx6s@//FkpFbz@DQ)

Saved 8 bytes thanks to @ovs' [observations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242000/97916).

### Explanation

Takes input as `b a`.

```
         ! 9 6
over     ! 9 6 9
*        ! 9 54
dup      ! 9 54 54
present  ! 9 54 "54"
reverse  ! 9 54 "45"
dec>     ! 9 54 45
-        ! 9 9
=        ! t
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 31 bytes

```
lambda a,b:`a*b`==`a*b-b`[::-1]
```

Using the logic that
$$
ab = \operatorname{rev}( (a-1)b ) \iff ab = \operatorname{rev}(ab-b)
$$
-2 thx to @dingledooper

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUxLDoIwEN33FBNWYAop/09Sl57AnZrQBohNCiW0Ljh9pUbBxcyb95k3r@appsQO9G4lG3nHgGHetOzEW0odhLy9NU0YP6wYZ7UY0KtGg1pAgpgcibTpxNQgEFhRGelZCuN7QM/gBci1UfEVf3QyPguwA75J8/IRMMeD2wFWgS2gdgXX5dWjDHJ3X5jUPUohictq99IMElIe2RKqI1sQAvE2u5AVG6@OdBWXkJP07wNqQnb/DQ)

### Other solutions:

#### Python 2, 31 bytes

```
lambda a,b:`a*b`[::-1]==`a*b-b`
```

Using the logic that
$$
\operatorname{rev}(ab) = (a-1)b \iff \operatorname{rev}(ab) = ab-b
$$
-2 thx to @dingledooper

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLDoIwEEX3/YoJKzCFlPcjqUu/wJ2a0AaITQoltC74@kqNgot5nDt37ryap5oSO9C7lWzkHQOGedOyE29vTRPGD0odhLy1YpzVYkCvGg1qAQlichBp04mpQSCwojLSsxTG94CewQuQS6PiK/5wMj4LsBt8k@blI2COB9cDrAJbQO0CrsurRxnkbr8wqXuUQhKX1X5LM0hIeXhLqA5vQQjEW@1CVmxcHe4qLiEn6d8H1ITs9zc)

#### Python 2, 34 bytes

```
lambda a,b:a*b-int(`a*b`[::-1])==b
```

Using the logic that
$$
ab - \operatorname{rev}(ab) =b
$$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUxLDsIgEN1ziokrMdjQj/0luPQE7tREiG0koaUBXPT0CEZbFzPzfvOm2T31mPmeXb3ig3hw4ES0fCf2cnTbewD3S9vu0xtmTHg5TNo4sLNFvTagQI6RJNY95NgikEQzldhJSbfdADvCBqNYyORX/NHQzTGJRwRpMh@BCNLHjYnGvoQmFpzNq0MFHCI@cWU7lEOWVvXi5QVktFqzFdRrtqQU0jCLUJSB12u6Tis40PzvAxpKF/8N)

^Credits to @ovs for the equations!

Comment: `(a-1)*b` -> `a*b-b`

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
:‹"*÷Ṙ=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI64oC5XCIqw7fhuZg9IiwiIiwiNlxuOSJd)

```
  "     # Pair the first input with
:‹      # Itself decremented
   *    # Multiply both by the second input
    ÷   # Push both to the stack
     Ṙ= # Is one reversed equal to the other?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
ＮθＮη⁼×θη⮌×⊖θη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oLmZ8B5AcUZeaVaLgWlibmFGuEZOamFmsU6ihkaOooBKWWpRYVp0IFXVKTi1JzU/NKUlOA5oBUAIH1///GJgpGBuaW/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for a reversed pair, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ              First input as a number
  Ｎη            Second input as a number
      θ         First input
     ×          Multiplied by
       η        Second input
    ⁼           Equals
           θ    First input
          ⊖     Decremented
         ×      Multiplied by
            η   Second input
        ⮌       Reversed
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 40 bytes

```
f(a,b)=d=digits;d(a*b)==Vecrev(d(a--*b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzbCoMwDIZfJXjVjhRSndox3GPsRrzIPFGQUZwM9vRdzFW@/5TEe3RrynkxjC/bTd0U13h87pPhi@juOY/7/DUinRPDZk5p@xkG94C0x/chWJyigJG3zSwIbC1C3zcIt0HgilCft0IofRsUxSup1bhFUK8hQvBEOmlODJoHL42aKu3ISyK1q9LL0A@DzX8)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 41 bytes

Expects `(a)(b)`. Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
a=>b=>[...a*b+''].reverse().join``==a*b-b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBNDoIwEEb3noIdHQ2l5bcsytITuDMmFCwGQqhpletja0yMBpjFbOblfTPTi0mYRnf3RzCqq5xbPgte1rw8Y4zFvj74/gVrOUltJALcq26sKs7tJKjnRo1GDRIP6oZalAEqADxXYeid9FPufoEEUPoFjmIw/0QMKKI5c9CyIraOiOQuZxnIAbHtjIwQQNQ2WCOSzAFsPYRRG5OSeF3hfkFIsXFIRO2m9AO8FfML)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 55 bytes

```c
c;r;f(a,b){for(r=0,c=~-a*b;c;c/=10)r+=9*r+c%10;r-=a*b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHZboMwEHzPV2yRkDiMYifNgVz3pepXNFEFxqSoLYlspKJG9NNL11xKoiKzeGd2BhjL6CBl20quee4lJPXP@VF7WlAixU@UBCmXXM4Fo74ORRzoULqMch0JSzVtUVbwmRSl58N5BnhZoFKmMq/Jyx4EnNcE7gksceFjQ2BNKSKIbpntEF@wht9o014bE1gRWLDNFivdYIsbZg0Y3VqSom9MqSUuTVR9UrJSWe/CCFhFt@i4H@ogksfSVCDfEh1gVfJd6V7r7Ornxa6On/BeOQQu@6UzqDEx8Ox7izJTNcooH7YPYIpvdcy98Yv8@QAEE8IhDLtpvzPrYxz/JEG3Mc5uaM@v@HTi0395g/ydPVhI/WtGITPldCs9aRzJPcfNCLgZRI@2umZXYgTWi4AhU1BGCLUf3JtZ0/7K/CM5mDb6@gM)

Inputs two integers \$a\$ and \$b\$.
Returns a falsy value if these two numbers are a reversed multiple pair or a truthy value otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 14 bytes

```
Jpdjp^-..*<-==
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYoxCoAwEAT7vGJrQblLYhLBfMDOD1iINmIRlWAhvj0eWCzDzu6cz329jryWZ0hXGdKypalumqqvYyw5be@9j8Whg7JooQw0@yC00OTFekhzRGCJsk4YRAf2aMnIhI5IhNGMwFBM/@MD)

Takes input as array of pairs {a b}

```
J   # Duplicate
pd  # Product of array
j   # Swap
p^  # Push elements to stack (b, a)
-.  # Decrement
.*  # Product
<-  # Reverse digits
==  # Equal
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{"#{a*=b}"==(a-b).digits*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6laSbk6Ucs2qVbJ1lYjUTdJUy8lMz2zpFhLXb32f4FCWrSZjmUsF4hhrmMBYZgZGOgYGhhAOCZmQLaFZex/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>43</s> 33 bytes

```hs
a?b=a*b==read(reverse$show$a*b-b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NCsIwEITvfYo95KCCsNu/pIfQZ9nQQIu1laTo48dEPKwev4@ZYWaON7@uKfHoLF@ctcHzdAr@6UP0Ks77S2V9ded052UDC9NewSMs2wEKoIcRBsFN5pq0kaotDrWMtaVHaIb/KcSfWFadYJ1ZTveInx0UzlBJddjICzWVJglF@H0AVXoD)

- I haven't thought `reverse` was available in prelude, no reason to use foldl(flip(:))""String

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 55 bytes

```
\d+
$*
1,
,
1(?=.*,(1+))
$1
,
,$`
1+
$.&
+`(.),\1
,
^,$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYu7CgIxFAX78x1Rks0h3Jvs5lGIpT@xSAQtbCwW/z/GamCYOV7f9@cxTvbWx/70MAuUINReL2GhVe8cjE5D06EzCGf4boPj/rd3mjEyG1ZuSIxaKtLKKKWhsCKLUEWw5onaULVwk4S5iDSkqKz6Aw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1,
,
```

Decrement `a`.

```
1(?=.*,(1+))
$1
```

Multiply `a-1` by `b`.

```
,
,$`
```

Add that to `b` giving `(a-1)b,ab`.

```
1+
$.&
```

Convert to decimal.

```
+`(.),\1
,
^,$
```

Test whether the results are mirror images of each other.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <sup><s>47</s></sup> 45 bytes

```
func[a b][(to""a * b)= reverse to""a - 1 * b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxLCsIwAET3PcWjKxWEpGmbRPASbkMW/STopi2xev0YdWAYePAmhTnfwux8FS85vpbJDYzeHfa1rgdOjMcrKbxDegb@7Iz8cp/jmsIw3fkZuB5LS4eikdqgWhqhLRpDLwSytO3LGIuRmk4oiiKERTWyIO8qSrb0WHYi5bTy@QM)

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

Prompts for a then b. Minus 2 bytes using rearrangement logic

```
(⍎⌽⍕n-b)=n←(b←⎕)×a←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##JYuxDcIwEEX7m8JlUlg628R2CgZAAjGDE2SEZAWkVCwAFCSiiZiGik28iLkTje/pv@dwSfJwDel8lH0K43jqS56X3TbfXgaINnsiBflxj6XK05yfnzwtg@zq9UCm6uihrP6@w58KpVAiWGghwkpAQ8cI0Mp5Jlo0OnZOAC8WUYBC5NoyeZZekW7QcCCgReTRaEV/1A8)

Answer (score 2):

## BQN, <s>33</s> 22 Bytes

<s>This seems too long.</s>

A little better.

```
{(×)=•BQN⌽•Fmt×-1}
```

[Try it!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkHso8J2VqMOX8J2VqSk94oCiQlFO4oy94oCiRm108J2VqcOX8J2VqC0xfQo2IEYgOQ==)

*¯11 bytes thanks to @Razetime*

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 41 bytes

```
L$`.+,
*$'*_,$($^$.(*$'*))*_$'*
^(_+),\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxDgIhEEbh/j/HGIGdbGaAheEENh7BLGthYWNh9v6I1ZdXvO/rfH@eOi7udow7HevCCHQNncnRTqv7h/ehT7C7vnh@KI1RuCHzhsRRqyFljlIbKhuKCKsIcplYg2nlTRLmItKQorLpDw) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Based on @ovs' 05AB1E answer.

```
L$`.+,
```

Match `a` as `$&` (Retina ignores the trailing comma when performing arithmetic) and `b` as `$'` and replace the whole input with the result.

```
*$'*_,$($^$.(*$'*))*_$'*
```

Calculate `a*b` and also `rev(a*b)+b` in unary.

```
^(_+),\1$
```

See whether they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

## [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org), <s>86</s> <s>77</s> 70 bytes

```
a=6
b=9
s=Text(ab-b)
o=Sum(Zip(Take(s,c,c),c,Length(s)…1))==Text(ab)
```

[Try It On GeoGebra!](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/m3g8bgb6)

Input is `a` and `b`, output is `o` as `true` if `a` and `b` are a reversed multiple pair, `false` otherwise.

The example input shown in the code is `a=6` and `b=9`, but you can change these values to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>20</s></sup> 14 bytes

```
*=|.&.":@(*<:)
```

-6 bytes, thanks @Jonah

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NCsIwEITveYqhB2uLht30JzEYEARPnnwFsS1efAHx1eNGhQQPu/DNzgx7j5WuZwSPGhsQvMxW43g5n2IbnnqlK39Yt3vfxEZNQc8vpW7X5QFGwIgJuy@SYC84IJ87YcPWFUqyGLJFyIrikHkkEoVl51g/fiRXxByn4EAd/t4hKlyd4VTPRT/TrwvxDQ)

Comment: Taking args in reverse order, `*=|.&.":@(*<:)` for 14 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NCsIwEITveYqhB2uLht30JzEYEARPnnwFsS1efAHx1eNGhQQPu/DNzgx7j5WuZwSPGhsQvMxW43g5n2IbnnqlK39Yt3vfxEZNQc8vpW7X5QFGwIgJuy@SYC84IJ87YcPWFUqyGLJFyIrikHkkEoVl51g/fiRXxByn4EAd/t4hKlyd4VTPRT/TrwvxDQ "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 79 bytes

```php
$a=trim(fgets(STDIN));$b=trim(fgets(STDIN));echo $a*$b==(int)strrev($b*($a-1));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkVRJtS4oyczXS0lNLijWCQ1w8/TQ1rVWSsImmJmfkK6gkagFlbTUy80o0i0uKilLLNFSStDRUEnUNgUr@/zfjsgQA)

With the help of Github Copilot

Comment: Instead of all of this, you can just do `fn($a,$b)=>$a*$b==+strrev($b*($a-1));`. This creates an anonymous function and does the casting to a number in fewer bytes. This syntax was introduced in PHP 8.0. You can see it working for yourself here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d26cb3ea5513512044fd100d5cc62e306e8e6e23

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
`(*x¬*=
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##HYqpEYAwEEX9r2IlE/U350bQCxhAwGAQFEUVNBYyyHcc87Wt5760Ng3ufh83tpalIojXYghRPEtFzKK0ip7IjpJQxJDJ7gnTIokBwauYQvnfHw)

**Explanation:**

```python
`        # Duplicate the top two items, using the implicit inputs
         #  STACK: b,a,b,a
 (       # Decrease the top item
         #  STACK: b,a,b,a-1
  *      # Multiply the top two together
         #  STACK: b,a,b*(a-1)
   x     # Reverse the top integer
         #  STACK: b,a,reverse(b*(a-1))
    ¬    # Reverse rotate the stack:
         #  STACK: reverse(b*a(-1)),b,a
     *   # Multiply the top two again
         #  STACK: reverse(b*a(-1)),b*a
      =  # Check if the two are equal
         #  STACK: reverse(b*a(-1))==b*a
         # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 31 bytes

Using bitwise operators

```sql
PRINT-1/~(@*@b^reverse(@b*~-@))
```

**[Try it online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9fc7f0105c4dda09629b30cabc563aba)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 56 bytes

```julia
(a,b,d=digits,s=string)->s(d(a*b))==s(reverse(d(a*b-b)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc5JCsMwDAXQfU@hpV0UkDJn4dKrJGSoS2nASofbuy6lQUs9/v/o@rj5nt9xdtH0OODoRr/4TVCcbMHfF5udxIymPw7WOicmTM8pyPSjLKGNZ7msL5hNjdDZw/8qESoL@1kg5Ny0WlIip6ZT1CDoRE2EwESKyvorrS61nGoVFbqYPiHSoSLntM1KmPal@AE)

Pretty straightforward answer, with nothing particularly clever to it (unfortunately).

Comment: 33 bytes: `a+b="$(a*b)"==reverse("$(a*b-b)")`.

Comment: @dingledooper I always forget about the operator trick  That seems different enough to merit a separate answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 15 bytes

```
nn&s*SrJlf,*=u;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z8vT61YK7jIKydNR8u21Pr/f2MuI0NzCwA)

```
nn               - read two numbers from STDIN
  &s             - save the entries to the backup cell
    *            - multiple the two numbers passed in
     S           - convert integer to individual digits on stack
      r          - reverse stack
       J         - re-compose digits on stack into a integer
        l        - restore saved numbers
         f       - flip top two entries
          ,      - decrement the top of stack
           *     - multiple top two entries
            =    - compare the two entries on the stack
             u   - print "1|0" from comparison
              ;  - exit the program
```